# Assigning char array to char array in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, char

can you help me with this code, i am able to copy arr into arr2(from index 1 and further, i cannot figure index 0 till now), but some others can't.
Can you tell if anything's wrong here?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
        char arr[] = "char_arr_one";
        char arr2[] = {arr};
        printf("%s\n%s\n", arr, arr2);
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<13;i++){
                printf("%c %c\n", arr[i], arr2[i+1]);
        }
}
```

this is working on my system!

Comment: Which system does that work on?  GCC complains: `warning: initialization of ‘char’ from ‘char *’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]` (even with no warning options explicitly enabled).  You should heed compiler warnings — the compiler knows more about C than you do.

Comment: Arrays are not pointers, and arrays cannot be assigned to.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Earlier I did the same on sololearn and now i have done the same on Ubuntu 16.01. Even Hackerrank is giving me the same answer!

Comment: In Ubuntu it's 5.4.0.

Comment: This is not legal C code. Whatever results you see happen by sheer accident. Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842756/why-should-i-always-enable-compiler-warnings

Comment: You may also want to look at this slightly modified version of your code https://ideone.com/kSNSJA

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Can you explain why is that?

Comment: Yes: that's because you ignored conpiler warnings. You should never. Ever. EVER ignore compiler warnings. When you do, weird things happen and you have no idea why. Do not run code that compiles with warnings. Just don't do that. It's that simple.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. That was really "HELPFUL"!

Comment: What kind of help do you expect?

Comment: Now you have an example which shows why it does not work in my answer

Comment: regarding: `char arr2[] = {arr};`  This assigns a pointer to the character array `arr2[]`  This does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C standard does not permit to assign an array to another array:

```
char arr[] = "char_arr_one";
char arr2[] = {arr};        // This does not work.
```

Why it works on a specific implementation as you´d stated, I don´t know, but generally it should not be possible to compile that code without at least one warning.

So maybe you disabled or even ignored warnings?

One link to that context, here:
[Why should I always enable compiler warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842756/why-should-i-always-enable-compiler-warnings)

Nonetheless, this doesn´t bring you the desired result of copying the string `"char_arr_one"` into `arr2`.

If you want to store the string, stored inside of `arr`, in `arr2` you can use `strcpy` in the header `string.h`:

```
char arr[] = "char_arr_one";
char arr2[13];                // You need to provide the amount of elements, at least
                              // as much as are required to store the string inside arr
                              // the null character.
strcpy(arr2,arr);             // Copies the string in arr into arr2.
```

Note, that you need to specify the elements of `arr2`, which need to be at least as much as are required to store the string of `"char_arr_one"` plus the terminating null character `\0`, when defining `arr2`. In this case, `arr2` needs to have at least 13 `char` objects.

You could also "automatically" detect the size of `arr` by using the `sizeof` operator:

```
char arr[] = "char_arr_one";
char arr2[sizeof(arr)];       // Automatically detects the size of `arr` and provides
                              // it for specify the required amount of elements for storing 
                              // the string in arr + the null character.

strcpy(arr2,arr);             // Copies the string in arr into arr2.
```

Beside that, the third argument of `arr2[i+1]` inside the `printf` call will get you into Undefined Behavior. At the last iteration, it would print something what lies beyond the array of `arr2`. So change that to `arr2[i]`.

---

The corrected code shall be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
        char arr[] = "char_arr_one";
        char arr2[sizeof(arr)];

        strcpy(arr2,arr);

        printf("%s\n%s\n",arr,arr2);

        for(int i = 0; i < 13; i++){
                printf("%c %c\n", arr[i], arr2[i]);
        }

        return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
char_arr_one
char_arr_one
c c
h h
a a
r r
_ _
a a
r r
r r
_ _
o o
n n
e e
```

Answer (score 1):

in C you can't assign array to array.

You need to copy it yourself

```
    char arr[] = "char_arr_one";
    char arr2[sizeof(arr)];

    memcpy(arr2, arr, sizeof(arr);
```

or

```
        for(size_t index = 0; index < sizeof(arr); index++)
        {
            arr2[index] = arr[index];
        }
```

If I make your example a bit less trivial (by adding another variable) the result is obvious. It does not work.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
        char arr[] = "char_arr_one";
        char another[] = "it does not work for sure";
        char arr2[] = {arr};
        printf("%p %p\n", (void *)arr, (void *)arr2);
        printf("%s\n%s\n", arr, arr2);
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<13;i++){
                printf("0x%02hhx - '%c' 0x%02hhx, '%c'\n", arr[i], arr[i],
                  arr2[i], (arr2[i] >= 32 && arr2[i] <= 127) ? arr2[i] : ' ' );
        }
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/dvLcqq

And the result is:

```
0x7fff4a68b84f 0x7fff4a68b82f
char_arr_one
Oit does not work for sure
0x63 - 'c' 0x4f, 'O'
0x68 - 'h' 0x69, 'i'
0x61 - 'a' 0x74, 't'
0x72 - 'r' 0x20, ' '
0x5f - '_' 0x64, 'd'
0x61 - 'a' 0x6f, 'o'
0x72 - 'r' 0x65, 'e'
0x72 - 'r' 0x73, 's'
0x5f - '_' 0x20, ' '
0x6f - 'o' 0x6e, 'n'
0x6e - 'n' 0x6f, 'o'
0x65 - 'e' 0x74, 't'
0x20 - '' 0x20, ' '
```

Comment: I copied my above code to hackerrank and it's working there!

Comment: @ArooshRana if you know better - why do you ask questions? But I can assure you. It does not work there.

Comment: @P__J__ I am asking for what new I find. It's not something I am arguing about.

Comment: @ArooshRana you did not learn or discover anything new here. Every time you print the `arr` accessing its elements by reading out of bounds `arr2` which is 1 byte long and it is before the `arr` as they are stored on the stack and newer elements have lower addresses.

Answer (score 1):

> i am able to copy arr into arr2(from index 1 and further, i cannot figure index 0 till now), but some others can't. .....

On what basis you are sure about this? I do not see any code which is copying `arr` to `arr2` **from index** `1` and further.

Look at the `gcc` compiler warning on the statement which is, as per you, copying `arr` to `arr2` from index `1`:

```
<source>:5:24: warning: initialization of 'char' from 'char *' makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]

5 |         char arr2[] = {arr};
```

Meaning of this warning -
The array name `arr` decays to pointer and the pointer is converted to integer and assigned to the first element of `arr2` (element at 0<sup>th</sup> index of array `arr2`).
Note that if the `char` is signed then the result of this assignment will be implementation defined<sup>1)</sup>.

The way the `arr` and `arr2` placed in stack on your machine, you may be getting expected output but on a different platform/architecture you may get different result. Note that C language standards do not specify how a function local variables should be placed in stack. The standards even do not have a single mention of memory segments (stack, heap etc.) in it. These things are completely dependent on the underlying platform/architecture. Standards only talk about the scope and life of variables.

> Can you tell if anything's wrong here?

Since you have omit the dimension of `arr2`, the compiler computes it based on the size of the initializer. The initializer of `arr2` is having only `1` element. So, the size of `arr2` will be `1` i.e. `arr2` is a `char` array with just one element. Here you accessing the `arr2` beyond its size:

```
    for(i=0;i<13;i++){
            printf("%c %c\n", arr[i], arr2[i+1]);
                                      ^^^^^^^^^
```

Accessing an array beyond its size is [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior). **An undefined behavior includes it may execute incorrectly (either crashing or silently generating incorrect results), or it may fortuitously do exactly what the programmer intended.**

---

1) From C Standards#6.2.5p15

> `15 The three types char, signed char, and unsigned char are collectively called the character types. The implementation shall define char to have the same range, representation, and behavior as either signed char or unsigned char.45)`